# Overflow after inserting image in column

Tags: python, css, django, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know this is a one setting issue but I'm quite new and don't know what the exact terminology to get the answer i'm looking for.

I'm using `Bootstrap-3.3.7` on Django 1.11

When I insert an image the first column and row I get an overflow into the second column.

With image

[image]

Columns without image works correctly.

[image]

```
                          <div class="tab-content">

                          <div class="tab-pane active" id="{{vg.grouper.id}}{{fg.grouper.id}}hari_ini">

                            <div class="row">                               
                            {% for sg in show_list2 %}
                            {% if sg.grouper %}
                            {% for sh in sg.list %} 

                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-spl col-xs-npr">
                                <div class="contain">
                                                {% load static %}

                                                {% ifchanged %}
                                                <img src='{% static sh.film.poster %}' width= 100% >
                                                {% endifchanged %}
                                </div>          
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-npl col-xs-npr">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                                <p class=p1>{{ sh.show_time_today }}</p>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-npl col-xs-npr">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>

                                            <p class=p1>{{ sh.rps_price }}</p>



                                        </li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-npl col-xs-npr">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>

                                            <p class=p1>{{ sh.rps_price }}</p>



                                        </li>
                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}

                                    </div>
                          </div>
```

I've tried the css below which does not help.

```
.contain {
    height: /* max height you want */
    width: 95% /* max width you want */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've tried adding a row with col3 and col9 and with corresponding rows with col12 & col4 col4 col4 but the resulting flow became much more jumbled.

After applying Astik's changes the screen looks better with no null row/columns. I'm still seeing the overflow across all columns. Also the padding/alignment on text is not correct on right side. It this this is contributing to problem

[image]

```
 p {

 }
.p1 {
    color: gold;
 font-size: 3.8vw;
text-align: center;
 line-height: 60%;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding-left: 0;

}
li{
 list-style-type: none;
}
col-xs-*{

}
.col-xs-npr{
    padding-right: 0;
}
.col-xs-npl{
    padding-left: 0;
}
.col-xs-smpr{
    padding-right: 3px;
}
.col-xs-smpl{
    padding-left: 3px;
}
}
```

Comment: Given the answer, I think this case be closed under the official close reason of: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced_.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to solve the problem by opening the page in Firefox and looking at the rendered html closely in the Inspector (Ctrl + Shift + i).

From there I was able to see which sections were being populated with data. In the end, my `for` loops were not in the correct place. Furthermore, I discovered that I needed to put template tags inside div tags to when using if statements.

```
                <div class="tab-pane" id="{{vg.grouper.id}}{{fg.grouper.id}}besok">
                <div class="row">
                        {% for sg in show_list2 %}
                        {% for sh in sg.list %}
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-npr col-xs-smpl">
                    <div class="content">

                        {% if not sg.grouper %}
                        <div class="content">
                            {% ifchanged %}<p class=p2>{% tomorrow "%a, %d %b" %}</p>{% endifchanged %}
                            <p class=p1>{{ sh.show_time_tomorrow }}</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %} 
                    </div>
                </div>
```